# Can one use "known from" as "known for"?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I wonder if we can use the form "known from" instead of "known for" (saving the same meaning, of course).

For example: "NY is known from its beautiful Empire State Building"
instead of "NY is known for its beautiful Empire State Building".

Comment: Does your research bear out that phrase, "known from"?  Please share the results of your research in your question.

Answer (score 3):

No, they have different meanings.

- *Known **for*** means *(most) famous for*, so that's OK with the *Empire State Building*
  since that **is** something that NYC is famous for.
- *Known **from*** is quite different; it refers to the original source(s) of the information, as in
  *Hittite is known from cuneiform inscriptions from the 16th to the 13th Centuries B.C.*

Comment: +1 This answer has a Lawler weight of around 1.38. That may be a new record.